# AWS SQS Receive max number of message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I read the SQS Doc, it stated that `A single message batch request can include a maximum of 10 messages`

Do this apply to both send and receive? Because I was planning to receive 200 message at one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-batch-api-actions.html

There are only following batch requests:

- [SendMessageBatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessageBatch.html)
- [DeleteMessageBatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessageBatch.html)
- [ChangeMessageVisibilityBatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibilityBatch.html)

Single [ReceiveMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) action is limited up to 10.

For receive 200 messages - you need to poll queue multiple times until you read them all.